# How to set up XPath query for HTML parsing?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xpath, lxml

Here is some HTML code from http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/75-07-0 in Google Chrome that I want to parse the website for some project.

```
<div id="names">
<h2>Names and Synonyms</h2>
<div class="ds"><button class="toggle1Col"title="Toggle display between 1 column of wider results and multiple columns.">&#8596;</button>
    <h3 id="yui_3_18_1_3_1434394159641_407">Name of Substance</h3>
    <ul>
        <li id="ds2">
        ``  <div>Acetaldehyde</div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I wrote a python script to help me do such a thing by grabbing the name under one of the sections, but it just isn't returning the name. I think it's my xpath query, suggestions?

```
from lxml import html
import requests  
import csv 

names1 = []

page = requests.get('http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/75-07-0') 
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)

//This will grab the name data 

names = tree.xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_18_1_3_1434380225687_700"]')

//Print the name data 
print 'Names: ', names 

//Convert the data into a string  
names1.append(names)

//Print the bit length 

print len(names1)

//Write it to csv 

b = open('testchem.csv', 'wb')  
a = csv.writer(b)  
a.writerows(names1)
b.close()
print "The end"
```

Comment: I know nothing about pyton, but may be you need add `/text() `  - 
//*[@id="yui_3_18_1_3_1434394159641_407"]/text()

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: I've opened your link thereis not such element there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to inspect the string returned by `page.text` and not
just rely on the page source as returned by your Chrome browser. Web sites can
return different content depending on the `User-Agent`, and moreover, GUI browsers
such as your Chrome browser may change the content by executing JavaScript while
in contrast, `requests.get` does not.

If you write the contents to a file

```
import requests
page = requests.get('http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/75-07-0') 
with open('/tmp/test', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(page.text)
```

and use a text editor to search for `"yui_3_18_1_3_1434380225687_700"`
you'll find that there is no tag with that attribute value.

If instead you search for `Name of Substance` you'll find

```
<div><br>Search for this InChIKey on the <a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=%22IKHGUXGNUITLKF-UHFFFAOYSA-N%22" target="new" rel="nofollow">Web</a></div></div><div id="names"><h2>Names and Synonyms</h2><div class="ds"><button class="toggle1Col" title="Toggle display between 1 column of wider results and multiple columns.">&#8596;</button><h3>Name of Substance</h3><ul>
<li id="ds2"><div>Acetaldehyde</div></li>
```

Therefore, instead you could use:

```
In [219]: tree.xpath('//*[text()="Name of Substance"]/..//div')[0].text_content()
Out[219]: 'Acetaldehyde'
```

---

**How this XPath was found:**

Starting from the `<h3>` tag:

```
In [215]: tree.xpath('//*[text()="Name of Substance"]')
Out[215]: [<Element h3 at 0x7f5a290e85d0>]
```

The `<div>` tag that we want is not a child but rather it is a subchild of the parent of `<h3>`. Therefore, go up to the parent:

```
In [216]: tree.xpath('//*[text()="Name of Substance"]/..')
Out[216]: [<Element div at 0x7f5a290f02b8>]
```

and then use `//div` to search for all `<div>`s inside the parent:

```
In [217]: tree.xpath('//*[text()="Name of Substance"]/..//div')
Out[217]: 
[<Element div at 0x7f5a290e88e8>,
 <Element div at 0x7f5a290e8940>,
 ...]
```

The first `div` is the one that we want:

```
In [218]: tree.xpath('//*[text()="Name of Substance"]/..//div')[0]
Out[218]: <Element div at 0x7f5a290e88e8>
```

and we can extract the text using the `text_content` method:

```
In [219]: tree.xpath('//*[text()="Name of Substance"]/..//div')[0].text_content()
Out[219]: 'Acetaldehyde'
```

Comment: Where are you getting the page library? or is it the python GUI?

Comment: When I try to run it, I get an error about the with open loop
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/test' 
shouldn't it create the folder?

Comment: Did you open the file in write mode: i.e., `open('/tmp/test', 'wb')` or just `open('/tmp/test')`?

Comment: This is what I have  
`page = requests.get('http://chem.sis.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/rn/75-07-0')`
`with open('/tmp/test', 'wb') as f:`
 `f.write(page.text)`
`tree = html.fromstring(page.text)`

Comment: Save that code to a file (such as `script.py`) and run `python script.py`. It should work, assuming your indentation is correct.

Comment: I literally did so but I still get the error. I'm using Windows Powershell, does that affect it?

Comment: Change `/tmp/test` to some path were you like to write temporary files. (`/tmp` is the usual place for unix, not Windows).

Comment: Thanks I changed it to 'filename' and it created it!